# ¿Como cambiar el color de los botones al estar activada la imagen?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tengo un detalle con mi código. No lo logro conseguir que los puntos cambien de color cuando una imagen está siendo mostrada, solamente cambian de color cuando paso el puntero por encima del punto. ¿Cómo lo puedo modificar? Estoy elaborando un slider de imagenes y los puntos indican las imagenes, pero no logro hacer que el punto de la imagen "activada por asi decirlo" se ponga de otro color.

"Tengo un detalle con mi código. No lo logro conseguir que los puntos cambien de color cuando una imagen está siendo mostrada, solamente cambian de color cuando paso el puntero por encima del punto. ¿Cómo lo puedo modificar? Estoy elaborando un slider de imagenes y los puntos indican las imagenes, pero no logro hacer que el punto de la imagen "activada por asi decirlo" se ponga de otro color.Tengo un detalle con mi código. No lo logro conseguir que los puntos cambien de color cuando una imagen está siendo mostrada, solamente cambian de color cuando paso el puntero por encima del punto. ¿Cómo lo puedo modificar? Estoy elaborando un slider de imagenes y los puntos indican las imagenes, pero no logro hacer que el punto de la imagen "activada por asi decirlo" se ponga de otro color.Tengo un detalle con mi código. No lo logro conseguir que los puntos cambien de color cuando una imagen está siendo mostrada, solamente cambian de color cuando paso el puntero por encima del punto. ¿Cómo lo puedo modificar? Estoy elaborando un slider de imagenes y los puntos indican las imagenes, pero no logro hacer que el punto de la imagen "activada por asi decirlo" se ponga de otro color.Tengo un detalle con mi código. No lo logro conseguir que los puntos cambien de color cuando una imagen está siendo mostrada, solamente cambian de color cuando paso el puntero por encima del punto. ¿Cómo lo puedo modificar? Estoy elaborando un slider de imagenes y los puntos indican las imagenes, pero no logro hacer que el punto de la imagen "activada por asi decirlo" se ponga de otro color."

```css
.videos{
    background-color: chocolate;
    width: 52%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.vids{
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
.vids img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
.vids input{
    display: none;
}
.dots{
    background-color: darkkhaki;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 5px;
}
.dots label{
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    background-color: darkslategray;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 8px;
}
.dots label:hover{
    background-color: gray;
}
#vid1:checked ~ .v1{
    margin-left: 0;
}
#vid2:checked ~ .v2{
    margin-left: -100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Document</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link href="hoyy1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="videos">
            <div class="vids">
                <input type="radio" name="video-slide" id="vid1" checked>
                <input type="radio" name="video-slide" id="vid2">

                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5069216/pexels-photo-5069216.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" class="v1" alt="vid1">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5560206/pexels-photo-5560206.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" class="v2" alt="vid2">
            </div>
            <div class="dots">
                <label for="vid1"></label>
                <label for="vid2"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Creo que tendrías que definir una clase, por ejemplo .activo con los colores que te parezca. Luego el código de carrusel debe poner o quitar la clase activo al "botón" que corresponda. Si es el botón 2 pues poner en su classList.add('activo') y se la quitas al botón que la tenga., que lo buscas con getElementsByClassName('activo').

Comment: Eso parece JS. ¿No hay forma de que lo pueda realizar solamente con CSS?

Comment: Pues si claro, es Javascript. Supongo que el slider lo estás haciendo con Javascript. Pues en ese Javascript es donde harías lo que sugiero.

Comment: No, mi slider lo estoy realizando con puro HTML y CSS, por eso quería ver si había forma de realizarlo sin Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesante método para hacer un slider manual. La forma de lograr lo que buscas la tienes ya, jugar con los nodos hermanos. Sería colocar los botones como nodos hermanos de los inputs.
Habría que modificar el bloque con los botones para que quede en el mismo bloque que los inputs, modificar su calse para posicionalros abajo y crear los estilos para los hermanos de los checked.
Todo quedaría así

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
.videos{
    background-color: chocolate;
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.vids{
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
.vids img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
.vids input{
    display: none;
}
.dots{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
.dots label{
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    background-color: darkslategray;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 8px;
}
.dots label:hover{
    background-color: gray;
}
#vid1:checked ~ .v1{
    margin-left: 0;
}
#vid2:checked ~ .v2{
    margin-left: -100%;
}

#vid1:checked ~ .dots #b1{
    background-color: white;
}
#vid2:checked ~ .dots #b2{
background-color: white;
}
```

La class dots la cambio a posicionamiento absoluto y la coloco en el fondo con ancho a todo el bloque que la contenga.
Al final añado los estilos para los botones (b1, y b2) que están en el bloque dots,  hermano de vid1 y vid2.
Y el HTML sería

```
<body>
    <div class="videos">
        <div class="vids">
            <input type="radio" name="video-slide" id="vid1" checked>
            <input type="radio" name="video-slide" id="vid2">
            <input type="radio" name="video-slide" id="vid3">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5069216/pexels-photo-5069216.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" class="v1" alt="vid1">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5560206/pexels-photo-5560206.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" class="v2" alt="vid2">
            <div class="dots">
                <label for="vid1" id="b1"></label>
                <label for="vid2" id="b2"></label>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
</body
```

Como ves meto el bloque dots dentro del bloque con class=vids y a cada botón le añado un id. El color de los puntos activos los he puesto a blanco. Ah, he puesto tamños de acuerdo con la imágenes que he usado para probarlo.
Efectivamente sin Javascript se pueden hacer muchas cosas. :)

Comment: Si me funciona :) Igualmente estaba pensando en cambiar de lugar el div .dots dentro del div .vids pero el detalle que tenia era que los botones se solapaban con las imágenes y quedaban encima, pero creo que modificando el height de .vids pueden quedar abajo.